# Session expire even if expire_on_commit=False when I use pyramid_tm

Tags: python, transactions, pyramid

Just as the title said. All I want to do is get the return id (auto generate primary key) from the session after session.add. If I commit the transaction manually without using pyramid_tm all is fine, but when I start using pyramid_tm, it seems to ignore expire_on_commit. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't ignore expire_on_commit, it's just that the transaction isn't committed until after your code has run, so you need to flush and refresh.  This is how I do it:

```
thing = Thing()
Session.add(thing)
Session.flush()
Session.refresh(thing)
print thing.id
```

Comment: Yes, it works now, thanks. Though you can have your id after session.flush, but I think you use session.refresh to make sure.

Comment: The refresh isn't even needed here; SQLAlchemy already knows the id has not been set and will lot it automatically after the flush.

Comment: Note that transaction commit is not a factor here: the id is allocated by the SQL server, so is only available once the INSERT statement has been send to the server. SQLAlchemy normally does a flush automatically when you do a later query, but you can also force it when needed by doing session.flush() as mattjbray shows here.